Мониторинг уровня громкости отдельных приложений Windows
Есть ли библиотеки на python, которые могут мониторить звук отдельных приложений на Windows?
Задача состоит в том, чтобы при воспроизведении голосовых в телеграм, приглушать громкость других приложений. Возможно есть готовые решения, но нашел только встроенный функционал в windows, для приглушения звуков во время звонка.
Скорее всего для этой задачи подойдет другой язык; буду благодарен вашим советам.
